# QueryPath : What is the CSS selector of the current element

Tags: php, jquery, css

With PHP QueryPath it's easy  to find the content of in element in a HTML page

```
print QueryPath::withHTML('http://www.example.com', 'title')->text();
```

Output 'Example Domain'

What I'm trying to do is find content on a page and then find the CSS selector of the element that specific content is in.

```
htmlqp('http://www.example.com', '*')->filterPreg('/more/i')->last());
```

This finds the last elemente containing the string  'more'.
But i cannot find how to get the CSS selector of this element

I just thought QueryPAth would be an easy way to do this, but I also appriciate other solutions

Comment: There are many CSS selectors that identify a given element. Why do you need to get a CSS selector?

Comment: What does jQuery have to do with this ?

Comment: @adeneo I want to use the given selector in Jquery